# Minimal Set of group axioms

Tags: group-theory

Consider the following definition of a group:

A group $(G,\bullet)$ is

1.) A non-empty set $G\neq \emptyset$.

2.) A map $\bullet: G\times G\to G$ such that

- For all $g_1, g_2,g_3\in G$ we have 
  $g_1\bullet(g_2\bullet g_3)=(g_1\bullet g_2)\bullet g_3$.
- There exist an $e\in G$ for all $g\in G$, such that: $$e\bullet g= g$$ $$g\bullet e= g$$
- For all $g\in G$ there exists a $f\in G$, such that: $$g\bullet f=e$$ $$f\bullet g=e$$

Is this definition of a group "minimal" in the sense, that we can not forget about any of the previously stated properties? In other words: Are these properties independend or are some really consequences of the others? In particular I'm not exactly sure, weather or not we really need both $e\bullet 
 g= g$ AND $g\bullet e=g$.

Comment: You might also ask whether a weaker axiom2, like "there are (possibly equal) elements $e$ and $e'$ such that for all $g \in G$, $e \cdot g = g$ and $g \cdot e' = g$" would suffice, and you could *prove* (with the others) that $e$ must be the same as $e'$. (You might similarly require that every element have a left inverse and a right inverse, but not that they be the same, and then try to show that they must indeed be the same.)

Comment: Let $x \star y = y$ and check which of the group properties this operation $\star$ satisfies. So you cannot leave out two conditions. On the other hand, if $f \cdot g = g \cdot f = e$ and $e \cdot g = g$ then $g\cdot e = g\cdot (f \cdot g) = (g \cdot f) \cdot g = e \cdot g = g$. So you can drop the one condition $g \cdot e = g$ since it follows from the others.

Comment: @WimC: Can you write this as an answer and say a little more about, why we can not leave out more than one condition?

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus I did not say "any two conditions", just not two specific ones. I had no intention to be exhaustive, which is why a comment suffices for me. You do the math.  ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly I think it is more sensible to think of a group as a triple where $e$ is part of the structure, since otherwise (before proving $e$ is unique) it is not clear which $e$ one refers to in the axiom defining inverses.

After that, we can show that the following is a minimal set of axioms for a triple $(G,\cdot,e)$, where $G$ is a set and $\cdot$ is a map $G\times G\to G$ and $e$ is an element of $G$, to be a group:

1. For all $a,b,c$ in $G$, $a\cdot(b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c$;
2. For all $g$ in $G$, $g\cdot e=g$;
3. For all $g$ in $G$ there exists $h$ in $G$ such that $g\cdot h=e$.

**Proof:** Let $g$ be an element of $G$. By assumption there exists $h$ in $G$ such that $g\cdot h=e$. But since $h$ is $G$ there exists $k$ such that $h\cdot k=e$. We have $h\cdot g=h\cdot g\cdot e= h\cdot g\cdot (h \cdot k)= (h\cdot e)\cdot k= h\cdot k=e$ and hence $e\cdot g= (g\cdot h) \cdot g=g\cdot (h \cdot g)=g \cdot e=g$. This proves $(G,\cdot,e)$ is a group. It remains to establish minimality. For any set $S$ with at least two elements one of which we denote by $e$ we have:

- $(S,*,e)$, where $*$ is defined for $a,b$ in $S$ by $a*b=e$, satisfies 1 and 3 above, but not 2.
- $(S,\cdot,e)$, where $\cdot$ is define for $a,b$ in $S$ by $a\cdot b=a$, satisfies 1 and 2, but not 3.
- $(S,@,e)$, where $@$ is defined by for $a,b$ in $S$ by $a@b=
  \begin{cases}
  a & \text{if $b=e$}\\
  e & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$, satisfies 2 and 3 but not 1.

Comment: You can take $e$ out of the structure, you just have to make sure that the existential quantifier in 2.2 extends to 2.3. I.e. $\exists e,\forall g,(g\cdot e=e\wedge \exists f,f\cdot g=e)$

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I am aware of that but why would one want to?

Comment: ...because the definition is supposed to be as parsimonious as possible? (It also was stated this way in OP). Less is better.

Comment: @MarioCaneiro Less is not necessarily better. Universal algebraists would actually put inverses as part of structure (since then a group fits into the general framework).  One axiom and one operation could also be thought of as little as possible. But a group is not usually defined by $$x / ((((x / x) / y) / z) / (((x / x) / x) / z)) = y$$

Comment: The question was about how to minimize the group axioms though, so I think less is better in this context. The single axiom formulation is certainly worth a mention as well.

Answer (score 3):

Th briefest axiom system I ever saw for a group is an associative binary operation (written as  multiplication) on a non-empty set $G$ such that

for all $x,y \in G$  $$\exists! z\, (xz=y)$$ and $$\exists! z'\, (z'x=y).$$

Comment: That's a nice one.

Comment: @Bobby . But it takes some time to repeatedly use the "cancellation laws" to finally arrive at the "usual" axioms. :)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That is awesome.  This should be the selected answer.   Can we somehow go further because the symmetry of the two equations?

Comment: @ObjectsMorphisms . I dk what you mean by going further.

Answer (score 2):

The axiom $g\bullet e=g$  (or $e \bullet g = g$) can be deduced from the others.
$$g\bullet e= g\bullet (f\bullet g)==(g \bullet f) \bullet g= e \bullet g = g.$$

But we cannot drop the whole axiom 2.2 because the structure

```
*|g e
-+---
g|e e
e|e e
```

is associative and an inverse exists but $e$ does not satisfy (2.2).

Answer (score 2):

You can actually remove both 2.2.2 and 2.3.1 (or symmetrically 2.2.1 and 2.3.2), and this is optimal.

> A group is a pair $(G,\cdot)$ such that:
>
> - $\cdot : G\times G\to G$
> - For all $x,y,z\in G$, $(x\cdot y)\cdot z=x\cdot(y\cdot z)$
> - There exists $e\in G$ such that:
>
>   - For all $x\in G$, $e\cdot x=x$
>   - For all $x\in G$ there exists $y\in G$ such that $y\cdot x=e$.

In this case, $e$ and the inverse operation are unique and satisfy all the standard axioms of groups. Note that the quantifier over $e$ extends also to the definition of inverses, so it need not be in the structure. Let $e$ be given as above.

First a lemma: If $z\cdot z=z$ then $z=e$. Let $w\cdot z=e$. Then

$$z=e\cdot z=(w\cdot z)\cdot z=w\cdot (z\cdot z)=w\cdot z=e.$$

Now let $x\in G$. Let $y$ be such that $y\cdot x=e$. We will show that $x\cdot y=e$ and $x\cdot e=x$, which are the missing rules from this axiomatization.

To show $x\cdot y=e$ it suffices by the lemma that $(x\cdot y)\cdot(x\cdot y)=x\cdot y$:

\begin{align}
(x\cdot y)\cdot(x\cdot y)&=x\cdot (y\cdot(x\cdot y))\\
&=x\cdot ((y\cdot x)\cdot y)\\
&=x\cdot (e\cdot y)\\
&=x\cdot y\\
\end{align}

Thus $y$ is a two-sided inverse, and we can show $x\cdot e=x$:

$$x\cdot e=x\cdot (y\cdot x)=(x\cdot y)\cdot x=e\cdot x=x.$$