# Prove a result by assuming it's true and showing no contradiction

Tags: logic, fake-proofs

Preface: I'm not too experienced in propositional logic, just the basics, and I'm familiar with common proof methods (modus ponens, modus tollens, reductio ad absurdum, etc) but not so familiar to be comfortable here.

I have been trying to explain why a certain proof is not satisfactory (for my notes). It goes like this (an example):
Consider a group $G$ with identity $i$ obeying the typical group axioms (associativity, existence of identity, existence of inverse). Specifically:

$G1$: If $a,b,c \in G$, then $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$

$G2$: There exists an element $i \in G$, such that for all $a\in G$ , $a*i=a$

$G3$: For each element $a\in G$ there exists an element $a^{-1} \in G$ such that  $a*a^{-1}=i$

We wish to prove that, for the identity is defined by the postulate $a*i=a$, then we can show $i*a=a$. The 'proof' follows like this:
$$ i*a=a $$
$$ a*(i*a)=a*a $$
$$ (a*i)*a=a*a $$
$$ a*a = a*a $$
$$ (a*a)*a^{-1} = (a*a)*a^{-1} $$
$$ a*(a*a^{-1}) = a*(a*a^{-1}) $$
$$ a*i=a*i $$
$$ a=a $$
This last result is of course true. We've shown that $i*a=a$ does not lead to a contradiction, but this is not in and of itself a proof. We've also shown that under the same sequence of operations, both sides of $i*a=a$ are equivalent. This seems good, but it feels wrong. The proper proof, in my mind, would start with $a=a$ and derive $i*a=a$, but because we can do this by writing the above proof and working backwards, the above proof seems sound...

I thought that I could find a counterexample, because obviously if we started with something like $i*a=a*a$ then we might not be able to get to something like $a=a$. The trick, I guess, is that all of the steps in the above proof are reversible, but I don't know if that's necessarily true. So what can be said? Is there a good counterexample?

Comment: This looks like a classical logical fallacy: [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question). That proof is OK if each step is an "if and only if", but even in that case, I agree with you that the presentation is poor.

Comment: Did the proof point out that each step is biconditional; that step k is true if *and only if* step k-1 is true.  If this is stated then this proof is valid.  But if you want a better feeling proof just write all the steps in reverse order.  As every step is biconditional we have last step implies second to last step

Comment: Let's look at the reversed proof: how do you go from Step 2 to Step 1? You're using "left-cancellation", correct? But that assumes $ia=a.$

Comment: Why in your "axioms" the identity element was not defined as one such that for every $ a \in G $ : $$a*i=a=i*a$$ ?

Comment: @AzIf00 If the identity element is commutative, it might be desirable to remove one of the equivalences from the axioms.

Comment: @Azif00 See e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371204?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Just to be clear, would it be possible to state the precise list of axioms you're using? It is common to phrase the identity axiom as $$\exists i\in G\ \ s.t.\ \ \forall g\in G\ \ ig=gi=g$$ though there are many equivalent sets of axioms which are not so specific.

Comment: "Consider a group G with identity i obeying the typical group axioms "  But the typical group axioms *include* $i*a=a*i = a$.  If we don't include that axiom it isn't a group.  But there are examples of structures that are not groups that have left identities that are different than right identities.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element).  At any rate this proof is not valid in that it merely leads to a lack of contradiction which is not a proof.  And one can not go from $a*(i*a)=a*a$ to $i*a = a$ unless you have a left inverse and left identity.  .... but....

Comment: ... But ... *if* you also have axioms that you have left inverse $u$ and *left* inverse, $a^!$ where $a^{!}*a = u$.  We can prove that $u = i$ and $a^! = a^{-1}$ via $a=a*i$ so $a*a = a*(i*a)$ so $a^!*a*a=a^!a(i*a)$ so $u*a = u(i*a)$ and $a=i*a$. ... But that *WASN"T* what was being asked to be proved.

Comment: @fleablood: Or you could also write it this way: for every $a\in G,$ there exists a unique inverse $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=i.$ Therefore, we have \begin{align*}aa^{-1}&=i \\ \left(aa^{-1}\right)a&=ia \\ a\left(a^{-1}a\right)&=ia \\ ai&=ia. \end{align*} Therefore, if $ai=a$ for all $a\in G,$ then $ia=ai=a,$ and hence $ia=a.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister  That assumes that $a^{-1}a = aa^{-1} = i$.  If we have that $i$ is a right but not left identity, I don't think is fair of us to assume that $a^{-1}$ is both a right and left inverse.

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, exactly. It's not clear to me whether the OP has assumed right and left inverses. I wonder if you could prove this: $\forall\,a\in G, \;\exists ! \, b\in G$ s.t. $a=ib.$ If you could, you'd be home-free. [EDIT]: The OP has made it clear that left and right inverses are not assumed, as you surmised.

Comment: Sorry all, I originally didn't want to clutter the question, but obviously it's necessary! I've added the postulate set now

Comment: @SamGallagher: No problem! I do recommend clarity first, conciseness after.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478750/minimal-set-of-group-axioms) addresses your choice of axioms, I think.

Comment: Don't write math like a shopping list. If you have a sequence of sentences $A,B,C,$ it matters whether it's $A\implies B \implies C$ or $A\iff B\iff C$ or $C\implies B \implies A$.  Don't omit the  logical relationships between sentences. (And then it's much easier for you to understand too.)

Comment: Yes, with those axioms if we "reverse" the prove we have $a = ai\implies a*a = ai*a = a*ia$ but we can not "strip" off the $a$ from the *left* to get $a = ia$.  We can strip from the *right* but not from the left.  We will never be able to prove this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof reminds me of the many 'proofs' I have seen for induction, where instead of *showing that*:

$$\varphi(0)=[some \ formula]$$

or

$$\varphi(n+1)=[some \ formula]$$

it is instead *assumed*, and then through various manipulations one ends up with $0=0$, which is then followed by the remark: "See, it checks out!"

The big danger with this is that if you cannot reverse the process, then it is not a proof at all .... Indeed, showing that $0=0$ shows nothing at all ... *of course* $0=0$ is true!

Example: Suppose I want to prove that for all $n$:

$\Sigma_{i=0}^n i = 42$

(which is of course false!)

OK, so I say: Well, for the base I need to show that $\Sigma_{i=0}^0 i = 42$

Well, let's see:

$\Sigma_{i=0}^0 i = 42$

$0*\Sigma_{i=0}^0 i = 0*42$

$0=0$

"Aha!! QED!"

...except it's not QED at all ... Sure, you can *always* derive $0=0$. And, for that matter, you can always derive $a=a$. None of that shows anything at all.

So yes, you are right that you really want to *reverse* this process to count as a proof of $i * a = a$

OK, but if so, it seems like you could just start with $a * a = a* a$. That is, you'd get:

$$ a*a = a*a $$ (This is OK to start with, since it's always true)
$$ (a*i)*a=a*a $$ (since we're given that $a*i=a$)
$$ a*(i*a)=a*a $$ (because of Association)
$$ i*a=a $$ (Hmmmm ... why does that follow from $ a*(i*a)=a*a $?  That is not at all clear!)

One more thing:  The tile of your question raises red flags as well: just because some assumption does not lead to a contradiction does not mean that it is true ... or implied by the givens.

Example: I give you that $a=1$. Now, is $b=2$?  If you assume $b=2$, no contradiction will follow ... but it is clearly not implied by $a=1$

Also realize that *you* being unable to derive a contradiction does not mean there is no contradiction.... maybe there is a contradiction, but you just didn't see how to derive it.

And finally, just because you are able to infer $a=a$ does not mean that there is no contradiction. Again, you can *always* infer $a=a$. .. including from a contradiction ... indeed, *anything* follows from a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

(First some vocabulary.  If $a*i = a; \forall a \in S$ then $i$ is a right identity and if $u*a = a;\forall a \in  S$ then $u$ is a left identity.  If $aa^{-1} = i$ where $i$ is a right identity then $a^{-1}$ is a right inverse and if $a^!a = u$ where $u$ is a left inverse.)

First:  You are correct that a proof from conclusion to non-contradiction is not valid unless every step is reversible.

In this proof the irreversible step is the very first.  $a = ia \implies a*a = a*ia$ but $a*a = a*ia \not \implies a = ia$.

(But the statement $a*a = (a*i)*a = a*(i*a)$ is most certainly correct.)

Second:  The axioms of a group *INCLUDE* that $a*i = i*a = a;\forall a\in G$. so there is nothing to prove.

There are (among others) two axioms of a group. 1) that there is an identity element that is both a right and left identity. And 2) that for every element $a\in G$ there exists an element that if both a left and right inverse of $a$.

If we were to replace axiom 1) with simply that there is a right identity element that may not be a left identity but keep axiom 2) in tact then:

The step in the proof above is reversible. sort of.  $i = a^{-1}a = aa^{-1}$. so $a*a = a*(ia)\implies a^{-1}*a*a = a^{-1}*a*(ia)\implies a*a^{-1}*a = i*(i*a)\implies a*i = (i*i)*a \implies a = i*a$. And we have proven the stronger axiom 1)

Likewise if we were to replace axiom 2) with every element has a right identity but not necessarily a left inverse, but kept axiom 1) in tact we could prove the stronger 2) via

$i = hh^{-1}$  so $(h^{-1})^{-1}=i(h^{-1})^{-1} = hh^{-1}(h^{-1})^{-1}=h*i = h$.  So $h^{-1} h = h^{-1}(h^{-1})^{-1} = i= hh^{-1}$

But if we replace *BOTH* 1) and 2) with a weaker right identities exist and every element has a right inverse but say nothing of left inverses or left inverses, we can not prove a left inverse exist.

For a counter example look up a semigroup with a right identity and right inverse but not left indentities.

(Worth noting that a structure can have a right identity but not a left identity or a left identity but not right identity, but if a structure has both a left and right identity they must be same element. [If a structure has a left identity $u$ and  right identity $i$ then $u*i = u$ because $i$ is a right identity and $u*i = i$ because $u$ is a left identity.])